# Oracle SQL: show max when record in table exists

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, max

If record exists in the table i need to bring the data from the highest address record linked to the person.

Example:
John Doe have no address at all. Report need to still bring John Doe name but nothing as an address.
John Doe have 3 addresses with address number increasing. Report need to bring John Doe name and only the address with the highest address number.

Code I tried:

```
Select *
from person p left join address a on p.id = a.person and a.addressnumber = (select max(a2.addressnumber) from address a2 where a2.a_peron = p.id)
```

> Oracle returns error: ORA-01799: a column may not be outer-joined to a
> subquery
> 01799. 00000 -  "a column may not be outer-joined to a subquery"

I also tried

```
Select *
from person p left join address a1 on p.id = a1.person 
inner join (select a.person, max(a.addressnumber) MaxAdd, a.postcode, a.country from address a group by a.person, a.postcode, a.country) main on main.person = p.id and main.MaxAdd = a1.addressnumber
```

> This doesnt work neither due to the grouping.

I can probably get this done by using subqueries in the select itself together with the case statement but i would like to avoid that because I will be pulling a lot of data from the address so this would mean case statement with subquery for every single column.

Oracle 11g - 11.2

Any idea? :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` to rank your rows and only keep the last one:

```
select *
from person p
left join 
(
  select
    ad.*,
    row_number() over (partition by person order by addressnumber desc) as rn
  from address ad
) a on a.person = p.id and a.rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
select * from 
person p left join
(select a.person, max(a.addressnumber) MaxAdd, a.postcode, a.country from address a 
group by a.person, a.postcode, a.country) A
on p.id=A.person
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `row_number()`:

```
Select *
from person p left join
     (select a.*,
             row_number() over (partition by a.person order by a.addressnumber desc) as seqnum
      from address a
     ) a
     on p.id = a.person and seqnum = 1;
```